# C# Keeps Rounding Numbers Up Producing inaccurate results

Tags: c#, math, double, average, rounding

Ok so this is doing my head in, it keeps producing a slightly inaccurate result by rounding up the digits after the decimal. i need the exact value, not a rounded one!

So to start with take the following code:

```
int num1 = 10087;
int num2 = 9971;
int num3 = 9909;
int num4 = 9917;
int num5 = 9904;

double average = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) / 5;

double percentage = (10000 - average) / 100;
```

If this math is done on a calculator, the value of "percentage" is 0.424. But if it is run through the code the value gets rounded to 0.43 which is inaccurate. How can i stop this happening?

note: please do not question the 10000 number, i also need the result to be exactly the correct number (0.424) that is very important in this case!

Comment: Consider using decimal, instead of double if accuracy is a concern.

Answer (score 5):

cast your average calc to double first

```
int num1 = 10087;
int num2 = 9971;
int num3 = 9909;
int num4 = 9917;
int num5 = 9904;

double average = (double)(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) / 5;

double percentage = (10000 - average) / 100;
```

Comment: technically, the issue occurred because all the operands of the division are integers, and so the computer performs an integer division, instead of a floating point division. Changing any of the operands to a float or double will force floating point division and fix the issue.  The approach above changes the sum of the 5 numbers in the numerator to a double, but changing the 5 to a double (by writing either `5d`, or `5.0`), would also fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

Just add a "d" after the numbers...

```
int num1 = 10087;
int num2 = 9971;
int num3 = 9909;
int num4 = 9917;
int num5 = 9904;

double average = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) / 5d;

double percentage = (10000 - average) / 100d;
```

The `d` tells the compiler to make these numbers double precision floating point values instead of integers (you can also just add a decimal point).  Without the "d" the numbers are integers and the computer performs integer arithmetic.  This means that

```
 9 / 5 = 1  instead of  1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly read the msdn form** it will help you to know the real reason
reference :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx

In it they already say that

**`When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer`**

[image]

Here you divide two integer so it's result is also int.
You just need to type cast that's all as the other people give ans

As ***Ela*** Write your code will look like

```
int num1 = 10087;
int num2 = 9971;
int num3 = 9909;
int num4 = 9917;
int num5 = 9904;

double average = (double)(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) / 5;

double percentage = (10000 - average) / 100;
```